# Sql query does not cooperate

Tags: java, derby

I get this weird error (java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException) when running my program. I didnt find something 100% related unfortunately. Any help would be appreciated!I am using Derby db.

```
String id = request.getParameter("gid");
stmt = con.createStatement();
String strSql = "select img from guitar where gid="+id+" ";
rs = stmt.executeQuery(strSql);
```

Comment: What type is column `gid`? Also, you'd be better using `PreparedStatement`

Comment: @MadProgrammer its an Integer

Comment: This may be a prototype, but in case it isn't, this is a great way to open yourself up to an SQL injection attack.

Comment: Did you try printing your query and executing it directly on database?

Comment: Are youy sure `id` is not empty?

Comment: @PM77-1 he should just debug its code and look at the generated string.

Comment: Maverick i did and it doesnt accept this kind of characters ("')

Answer (score 0):

```
String id = request.getParameter("gid");
```

'id' is string hence  :

```
String strSql = "select img from guitar where gid="+"'"+id+"'"+" ";
```

If you believe id has to be integer then convert it into integer before you pass it

Side Note : Your code is prone to sql injection, why don't use PreparedStatment and pass the variable

Comment: Yeah, I too supposed it was a String, but the field is an integer. So brace yourself for the downvotes... OP should learn how to post.

Comment: Probably the variable "id" contains non-numeric data.

Comment: unfortunately the request.GetParameter() is a type of string, it doesnt accept integers.

Comment: why don't you convert it into integer, then you can use your query

Comment: I tried to parse it but i got this error now: StandardWrapperValve[DisplayImage]: Servlet.service() for servlet DisplayImage threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[B@306151ac"

Comment: Of course you will get NumberFormatException . [B@306151ac is not a number. Technically, this tells me your gid is not a valid integer as you claimed

Comment: if it is not a number pass it inside a single quotes in the query. Look into my query

Comment: In database its defined as an Integer, i dont see why it should not be a valid integer

Answer (score 0):

The error says `SyntaxError` so probably you write something wrong in the `query`. `getParameter` returns a `string`. Based on the comments, you are trying to insert a `string` into a `integer` column. Try parsing it before.

I'm asuming you already established the conection to the DB and get a response, try `select * from guitar` that should get the list of records in the table, if you get a response the try to write directly the query in your DB. `gid` must be the name of a column, also `img` and try specifiying the database name as `[name].guitar`. Otherwise, your conection is failling

Also which `.jar` are you using? take a look at [JDBC](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using the following:

```
String strSql = "select img from guitar where gid=" + Integer.parseInt(idString);
```

Thanks for your help anyway!!